# ffmpeg coverting mov to mp4 gives no output

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have the following code:

```
    var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
        var proc = new ffmpeg({source: media.file.path, nolog: false})
            .withVideoCodec('libx264')
            .withVideoBitrate(800)
            .withAudioCodec('libvo_aacenc')
            .withAudioBitrate('128k')
            .withAudioChannels(2)
            .toFormat('mp4')
            .saveToFile(media.targetDir + media.getName() + '.' + '.mp4',
            function (retcode, error) {
                console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
            });
    fs.chmodSync(media.targetDir, '755');
```

This should (hopefully) convert an `mov` file to an `mp4` file. However that is not the case. Instead it goes through the code without printing any error nor other console messages and just continue?

So my question is what have I done wrong?

I know it's not alot to go for but I'll be ready to answer any question you might have!

Here is a picture of the `proc` variable after the  code has been executed:

[image]

Output of command

I ran the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i trim.F4A79C58-1141-412E-A713-2CF893F44055.MOV -c:v libx264 -vb 800k -c:a libfdk_aacenc -ab 128k -ac 2 test.mp4
```

And got the following output:

```
    ffmpeg version N-76045-g97be5d4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
  libavcodec     57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavformat    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x3d494c0] moov atom not found
trim.F4A79C58-1141-412E-A713-2CF893F44055.MOV: Invalid data found when processing input
```

**Attempted another file**

Here is the output for when i attempted another file (the other file might have been broken)

```
    ffmpeg version N-76045-g97be5d4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
  libavcodec     57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavformat    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 11.100 /  6. 11.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2015-11-04 15:28:54
  Duration: 00:00:02.21, start: 0.032948, bitrate: 751 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 91 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-04 15:28:54
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt709/bt709), 272x480, 647 kb/s, 24.04 fps, 24.08 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-04 15:28:54
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] profile High, level 2.1
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] 264 - core 142 r2491 24e4fed - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=800 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf57.4.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 272x480, q=-1--1, 800 kb/s, 24.08 fps, 18496 tbn, 24.08 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-04 15:28:54
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc57.6.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-04 15:28:54
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : Lavc57.6.100 libvo_aacenc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libvo_aacenc))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   54 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     226kB time=00:00:02.30 bitrate= 803.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    
video:187kB audio:37kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.346419%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] frame I:1     Avg QP:18.97  size:  5651
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] frame P:16    Avg QP:16.05  size:  6730
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] frame B:37    Avg QP:17.38  size:  2086
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] consecutive B-frames:  3.7% 11.1% 11.1% 74.1%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] mb I  I16..4: 18.0% 56.5% 25.5%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] mb P  I16..4:  3.5% 14.9%  5.9%  P16..4: 37.2% 26.1% 10.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 2.5%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] mb B  I16..4:  0.5%  1.3%  0.5%  B16..8: 40.2%  8.6%  1.7%  direct:18.9%  skip:28.3%  L0:47.4% L1:36.9% BI:15.7%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] final ratefactor: 15.06
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] 8x8 transform intra:60.0% inter:47.9%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 86.0% 88.2% 37.7% inter: 33.7% 48.0% 2.6%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] i16 v,h,dc,p: 27% 10% 44% 19%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 14% 36%  4%  4%  6%  5%  5%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 16% 22%  5%  7%  8%  5%  5%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] i8c dc,h,v,p: 50% 18% 25%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] Weighted P-Frames: Y:6.2% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] ref P L0: 66.8% 11.1% 14.9%  6.6%  0.6%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] ref B L0: 92.8%  6.0%  1.1%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] ref B L1: 97.6%  2.4%
[libx264 @ 0x356d660] kb/s:679.79
```

Comment: @aergistal ive added the output of the file

Comment: Looks like your input file is broken. Are you able to play it back?

Comment: @aergistal i am able to view it yes

Comment: @aergistal Hang on il try with another file and post the output

Comment: @aergistal added new output

Comment: Sorry for that but there is a typo in the command I told you to try. It's `ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libx264 -vb 800k -c:a libvo_aacenc -ab 128k -ac 2 test.mp4`. I was thinking of another lib.

Comment: @aergistal ive added the new output

Comment: The last one seems to be transcoded without issues. Still not working from node?

Comment: @aergistal No it is still not working from node sadly :S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94355/discussion-between-marc-rasmussen-and-aergistal).

Comment: Orig "savetofile" syntax has errors. 2 dots prior to ftype. No path seperator tween dir and last node  in the filName